# Using functions in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am applying a function on an rdd where each element of the rdd has two lists.

```
def update(x,y)
  return x[0]-y[0]
```

The above code gives an rdd with the above formula applied. But what I really want to do is:

```
def update(x,y):
  alist.append(x[0])
```

If I apply this function to every element of rdd as,

```
rdd.map(lambda x: update(x[0],x[1]))
```

It doesnt update the list. How do I do it? I want to update a list based on a logic applied to every element.

I am trying to write a code that keeps only the smallest number in memory.

Comment: can you please add example of inputs and expected output

Comment: Input:

alist=[]

rdd=(([5,1],[2,3]), ([2,2],[4,3]))

output is an updated alist

alist=[5,2]

Comment: Due to distributed nature of spark the variable will not work as in standalone system you might have to use accumalators or broadcast variable accordingly .Please find below link help to start .https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-accumulator-with-example/#:~:text=The%20PySpark%20Accumulator%20is%20a,through%20aggregation%20or%20computative%20operations.

Answer (score -1):

```
def update(x,y):
    alist = alist.append(x[0])
    return alist
```

Comment: No that doesnt solve it. I just tried

Comment: update function return correctly alist ? i update the answer

Comment: no but it will return an rdd like this.. with every row having different lists. defeats the purpose.